# Why must $k \ge 0$ if $\mathbb{P}[Y=k] \neq 0$ in this hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I am currently learning about the hypergeometric distribution. When sampling without replacement $n$ balls from $N$ balls in an urn where there are $B$ black balls and we specifically sample $k$ black balls, my textbook mentions the inequality $\max (0, n+B-N) \leq k \leq \min (n, B)$ as being a necessary condition for $\mathbb{P}[Y=k] \neq 0$, where $Y$ is the number of black balls we have sampled. I do not understand why $k \ge 0$ here, and I understand the other conditions we impose on our variables for this necessary condition. Why must $k \ge 0$ be in this condition? How does this make $\mathbb{P}[Y]= 0$? For context, here is the full statement:

> $$
> \mathbb{P}[Y=k]=\left(\begin{array}{l}
> n \\
> k
> \end{array}\right) \frac{\frac{B !}{(B-k) !} \frac{(N-B) !}{(N-B-(n-k)) !}}{\frac{N !}{(N-n) !}}=\frac{\left(\begin{array}{l}
> B \\
> k
> \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
> N-B \\
> n-k
> \end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{l}
> N \\
> n
> \end{array}\right)}
> $$
> for $k \in\{0,1, \ldots, n\}$. (Note that $\left(\begin{array}{c}m \\ j\end{array}\right)=0$ if $j>m$, so $\mathbb{P}[Y=k] \neq 0$ only if $\max (0, n+B-N) \leq k \leq \min (n, B)$.)

Comment: How can the number of sampled black balls be negative?

Comment: Note there is the "for $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$" in the sentence before that inequality.

Comment: In ${B \choose k }$ you want $0 \le k \le B$.  Similarly in ${N-B \choose n-k }$ you want $0 \le n-k \le N-B$, i.e. $n+B-N \le k \le n$.  Combining these give $\max (0, n+B-N) \leq k \leq \min (n, B)$.